# Error while creating SXA Site in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I have installed vanilla Sitecore instance 9.1 Initial release. After that installed Sitecore Powershell 5.0 was followed by SXA 1.9.

I'm trying to create a tenant or site to set up a local site facing an error like the one below.

```
ManagedPoolThread #15 19:09:40 ERROR Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Model' because it is null.
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Right-click the content node then creates a tenant folder.
2. Click create the tenant.
3. Right-click the created tenant and click site.
4. Enter the site name and choose the theme etc.
5. Powershell script starts to create the site.
6. Facing the below issue.

**Note:** Validated Tenant template (from tenant templates) has this base template {3BC304DB-FE8F-4AA8-B95C-8C331E823F4C} (/Sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/_Modules)

[image]

Comment: Find your tenant item and check `Tenant Templates location` field. Perhaps there is a broken link.

Comment: tenant and tenant template location filed are tagged properly.

Comment: you might want to check this link: https://tothecore.sk/2019/07/29/sitecore-sxa-create-site-failure/

Comment: I tried but this is not helpful for my issue

Comment: It fails to get tenant templates location in `Show-NewSiteDialog` cmdlet. Don't focus on the 2nd error. It just says that there is an attempt to pass empty/null model to `New-Site` cmdlet.
Your Tenant item has either broken link or for some reason item cannot be resolved. ($tenantItem.Templates) OR tenant item itself cannot be resolved. You can test this cmdlet (`Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Functions/Cmdlets/MultisiteContext/Get-TenantItem`) if it returns tenant when you will pass your site location as arg (probably tenant in your case not a site folder I am guessing).

Comment: What also caught my attention is weird path in the error message. It looks like it contains forbidden characters maybe this is causing error somewhere?

Comment: I tried with a valid path for the tenant. but still facing errors.